# Vector $A = 2i-6j+10k$ , Vector $B = 1i+Xj+5k$. Both vectors have same unit vectors. Then what is the value of $X$?

Tags: vectors

As both vectors have same unit vectors so it means that the cross product of these two vectors is equal to zero. 
But taking the cross products gives me.

$$(-30-10X)i-0j+(2X+6)k = 0 $$

I really do not know how to find the value of $X$ from this Equation. Please anybody help me.

Comment: What is the unit vector of a vector?

Comment: It's the directional vector: same direction, but magnitude of 1.

Comment: The vectors have *the same unit vector* (this is non-standard speech - assuming a semi-botched translation), iff they are scalar multiples of each other (probably it is required that the scalar is positive). So there exists a parameter $t$ such that $A=tB$. Looking at the $i$-components should tell you the value of $t$. Then looking at the $j$-components lets you determine $X$. You also need to look at the $k$-components to verify the claim that they have the same unit vector. No need to calculate the cross products (nothing wrong with calculating it either).

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of each coordinate to zero.

$i-$coordinate: $-30-10X=0$ implies $X=-3$.

$j-$coordinate: already $0$.

$k-$coordinate: $2X+6=2(-3)+6=0$.